# JQuery table highlighting using conditions

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, highlight

I using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to create several tables on my page. I want to use a [jquery highlighting](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin to highlight certain elements that aren't correct. For instance everything in the 'Enabled' column should be 'True', if it's not true it should be highlighted. However, in the 'Level' column they should be 'False'. Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Here is an example of the table:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| Cluster     | Enabled    |  Level   |
+-------------+------------+----------+
|       1     |       True |   False  |
|       2     |       True |   True   |
|       3     |      False |   True   |
|       4     |       True |   False  |
|       5     |      False |   False  |
|       6     |      False |   True   |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Here is a JSFiddle I spun up to play around: http://jsfiddle.net/t7f7m3hr/1/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `:nth-child()` selector on the `td` elements:

```
//Need to highlight 'Enabled' column if = True
$('#example td:nth-child(2)').highlight('True');

//Need to highlight 'Level' column if = False
$('#example td:nth-child(3)').highlight('False');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/4vwxqpz5/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Can you use highlight('True' or '1'); or some type of operator?

Comment: It looks like the highlight plugin simply uses `indexOf()` for the most part, so no, you cannot use operators.  However, you can chain your `highlight()` calls:  `.highlight('True').highlight('1');`.  Or, you could modify the small plugin to accept an array.

Comment: P.S. Looking at the code, the plugin should take an array, but it doesn't seem to work.